# Plesk email alert when admin login

Tags: linux, plesk

Can we set email alerts for Plesk admin login ? How can we do that in a Linux server ?

The email id should receive alert when someone logs in as admin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Plesk Event Manager you can use "Plesk user logged in" Event and some special script which should detect admin and send notification only in case of admin login.

Comment: Any event just for the admin login ?

Comment: also can anyone let me know the environment variable to be used to identify the user logged in via bash script ...